# Writing Outputs Using Python In A Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, directory, dockerfile, docker-run

I am trying to write a text (.txt) file to a local Desktop folder on Windows 10 after building a docker image (docker_run_test).  The docker build seems to work seamlessly using "docker build -t docker_run_test .", running the command from the working directory on the Desktop where the Dockerfile and Python script reside (C:/Users/mdl518/Desktop/docker_tests/).  The script is a simple print statement and writing of the print statement to a .txt file, but I cannot locate the output .txt.  Below is the associated Dockerfile, and the Python script.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ADD docker_test.py ./

RUN pip install pandas

CMD ["python3","./docker_test.py"]
```

The Python script (docker_test.py):

```
import os

print("This is a Docker test.")

with open('docker_test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("This is a Docker test.")
```

I have searched the contents of the Docker image as well, but cannot locate the output .txt within the image either.  Any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: Files will be written in the **container**. The container stops when the script ends. You should mount a volume to exchange files with the host.

Comment: It seems like you need add a command to prevent container to stop, then you can go into the running container to view the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mount/bind the folder where you want to see the results into the container.

Change the output filename to write in another folder, let say `/output`

```
with open('/output/docker_test.txt', 'w') as f:
```

And then ask Docker to bind host folder `%HOMEPATH%\Desktop` to container `/output`  :

```
docker run -v %HOMEPATH%\Desktop:/output docker_run_test
```

Not sure for `%HOMEPATH%` syntax as I'm a Linux user.

Comment: Benoit Courty et al. - Thank you for the further clarity, this answered my question perfectly and I am now able to access the output file in the local directory!  I will confirm your answer as the correct solution, thanks again!